# How do you parse a filename in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, tokenize, cut

I have a filename in a format like:

> `system-source-yyyymmdd.dat`

I'd like to be able to parse out the different bits of the filename using the "-" as a delimiter.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [cut command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)) to get at each of the 3 'fields', e.g.:

```
$ echo "system-source-yyyymmdd.dat" | cut -d'-' -f2
source
```

"-d" specifies the delimiter, "-f" specifies the number of the field you require

Comment: I'm curious why you added the # prompt.  Normally, that prompt indicates the root or superuser.  In generally, I'd think stuff like trying out the **cut** command would be better done as a regular user.  I'd have used the $ prompt.

Comment: Oh, yeah - good point. I must admit, I was logged in as root at the time and simply went for it - a bad habit, I know. Having said that, I think echo and cut are two of the least harmful commands :) But, for the sake of completeness, I'll certainly update the example right away. Cheers.

Comment: how can i assign the output to a variable? if i do `var = "system-source-yyyymmdd.dat" | cut -d'-' -f2` does not work.

Comment: Fantastic - an answer in 3 minutes - that's quicker than phoning a friend! - _originally added as an answer but that was deleted 6 years after I asked the question_ :)

Answer (score 10):

A nice and elegant (in my mind :-) using only built-ins is to put it into an array

```
var='system-source-yyyymmdd.dat'
parts=(${var//-/ })
```

Then, you can find the parts in the array...

```
echo ${parts[0]}  ==> system
echo ${parts[1]}  ==> source
echo ${parts[2]}  ==> yyyymmdd.dat
```

Caveat: this will not work if the filename contains "strange" characters such as space, or, heaven forbids, quotes, backquotes...

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your needs, [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is more flexible than cut. A first teaser:

```
# echo "system-source-yyyymmdd.dat" \
    |awk -F- '{printf "System: %s\nSource: %s\nYear: %s\nMonth: %s\nDay: %s\n",
              $1,$2,substr($3,1,4),substr($3,5,2),substr($3,7,2)}'
System: system
Source: source
Year: yyyy
Month: mm
Day: dd
```

Problem is that describing awk as 'more flexible' is certainly like calling the iPhone an enhanced cell phone ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Use the `cut` command.

e.g.

```
echo "system-source-yyyymmdd.dat" | cut -f1 -d'-'
```

will extract the first bit.

Change the value of the `-f` parameter to get the appropriate parts.

Here's a guide on the [Cut](http://learnlinux.tsf.org.za/courses/build/shell-scripting/ch03s04.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use the shell's internal parsing tools, which avoids the cost of creating child processes:

```
oIFS=$IFS
IFS=-
file="system-source-yyyymmdd.dat"
set $file
IFS=$oIFS
echo "Source is $2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and IMO best way) to do this is simply to use `read`:

```
$ IFS=-. read system source date ext << EOF
> foo-bar-yyyymmdd.dat
> EOF
$ echo $system
foo
$ echo $source $date $ext
bar yyyymmdd dat
```

There are many variations on that theme, many of which are shell dependent:

`bash$ IFS=-. read system source date ext <<< foo-bar-yyyymmdd.dat`

```
echo "$name" | { IFS=-. read system source date ext
   echo In all shells, the variables are set here...; }
echo but only in some shells do they retain their value here
```