# Merge CSV Files in Python with Different file names

Tags: python, csv

I'm really new to Python, so this question might be a bit basic. I have 44 csv files with the same headers and different file names. I want to combine them all into one file.

Each file is named "Votes-[member-name]-(2010-2014)-[download-time].csv"

The headers are do not include a column for the member name. I would like to add that as the first item.

This does part of what I want to do: [how to merge 200 csv files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-to-merge-200-csv-files-in-python). I'm just not sure how to iterate through files with different names, and add those names to the csv.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To iterate through the filenames you can use a similar method as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964691/2327328), using glob:

```
import glob
import os
os.chdir("/mydir")
for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    print files
```

Then, to add the member name to the header, you can print all the csv files line by line. If the line is a header, then print the member name on the same line as the header. (This isn't real code, but you can get the point)

```
for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    for lines in files:
         if line == header:
              print member,line
         else:
              print line
```

To split the CSV file and only use the member name (slightly modified so to not have a hyphen)

```
'Votes-[member name]-(2010-2014)-[download-time].csv'.split('-')[1]
```

**UPDATE for bash solution:** You can save this text and run it from the terminal (see [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/733901/2327328) here for Mac)

Generate CSV files (not necessary)

```
cat <<"EOF" > 1.csv
1,2,3
4,5,6
EOF

cat <<"EOF" > 2.csv
a,b,c
d,e,f
EOF
```

*Parse CSV files* - this script takes all CSV files and writes their file name as the first column. It also puts them into one file (note that I tested on debian linux, not mac).

```
rm -f all.csv
for fyle in *.csv ; do 
    echo | awk -v f=$fyle '{ print f","$0 }' $fyle >> all.csv
done
exit 0
```

**SECOND UPDATE:** If you want to remove the duplicate headers, the simplest way from the shell is to use 'grep -v', which selects all lines that don't match. You can pick a generic string that only exists in the header.

```
head -1 all.csv > nohead.csv # add one header line
grep -v "header string" all.csv >> nohead.csv # add rest of rows, with no headers
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. I'm on a Mac, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I added a solution using the bash shell.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for! Is there a way to only include the member name and not the whole file name?

Comment: Yes, you have to parse the file name as a string, then print it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11401139/2327328. Also, I added 2 more lines in order to not have duplicated headers.

Comment: But... to split the string I think python is the better tool. 'Votes-[member name]-(2010-2014)-[download-time].csv'.split('-')[1] Note that I removed the '-' from member name.

Comment: What about using cut in bash? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403/how-do-you-parse-a-filename-in-bash? The member name is spelled with an '_', my mistake. I'll look at splitting the sting in python though.

Comment: I did not know about 'cut', and it's nice to learn something new.