# Python merging files in directory

Tags: python, file, merge, concatenation, cat

I have thousands of files inside a directory with this pattern YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM:

- 201801010000.txt
- 201801010001.txt
- 201801010002.txt

I want to keep just the hours, so I need to merge 60 files into one for every hour of every day.
I don't know how to search into the filename to get the 60 files that i want. This is what I wrote

```
def concat_files(path):
    file_list = os.listdir(path)
    with open(datetime.datetime.now(), "w") as outfile:
        for filename in sorted(file_list):
            with open(filename, "r") as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read())
```

How do I name the file to keep the date? I'm using datetime now but it override the current filename. With my code I'm merging all files into one, I should merge every % 60 into a different file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge CSV Files in Python with Different file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684640/merge-csv-files-in-python-with-different-file-names)

Comment: If the filename is already in the format YYMMDDHHMM , can't you just remove the last two characters before the `.txt` extension ?

Comment: IMO a combination of `groupby` and `datetime.strptime` will solve this easily. Can you elaborate on input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not that far, you just need to swap your logic:

```
file_list = os.listdir(path)
for filename in sorted(file_list):
    out_filename = filename[:-6] + '.txt'
    with open(out_filename, 'a') as outfile:
        with open(path + '/' + filename, 'r') as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `glob` to get just files you want.  It lets you pass in a pattern to match against when searching for files.  In the last line below, it will only find files that begin with `'2018010100'`, have two characters, and end with `'.txt'`

```
from glob import glob

def concat_files(dir_path, file_pattern):
    file_list = glob(os.path.join(dir_path, file_pattern))
    with open(datetime.datetime.now(), "w") as outfile:
        for filename in sorted(file_list):
            with open(filename, "r") as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read())

concat_files('C:/path/to/directory', '2018010100??.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
file_list = os.listdir(path)
for f in { f[:-6] for f in file_list }:
    if not f:
        continue
    with open(f + '.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        for file in sorted([ s for s in file_list if s.startswith(f)]):
            with open(path + '/' + file, 'r') as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read())
            #os.remove(path + '/' + file) # optional
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While it's great to answer questions and we welcome it, it is also necessary to explain what did your code do as a solution. Add the relevant explanation to your answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19750124)